Value on the Y axis is being skipped in chart.js 3
Having a weird issue with a graph where a line (450,000) is getting skipped


options: {
    
    scales: {
        
        x: {

            
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Month'
            },
            stacked: true,
            grid: {
                display: false,
            }


        },
        y: {
            ticks: {
                autoSkip: false
            },
            position: "left",
            stepSize: 50000,
            min: 0,
            max: 500000,
            grid: {
                display: true,
            }

        },
        y1: {
            position: "right",
            stepSize: 5000,
            min: 0,
            max: 30000,
        }
    },
    plugins: {

        datalabels: {
            color: '#000000',

            display: true,
            font: { weight: 'normal' },
            padding: 6,
            formatter: function (value, context) {

                return numFormatter(value);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'bottom'
        },
        
    },



Any ideas? I have tried adjusting the padding in addition to what is being shown above, as well as turning off auto skip, but nothing I do seems to add that line back in. If anyone has had this issue, please let me know if you were able to fix it!

Can you recreate it on the StackBlitz with the data?
